# How to use beginning and endline markers in regex for Java String?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

Why doesn't the following change the text for me in Android?

```
String content = "test\n=test=\ntest";
content = content.replaceAll("^=(.+)=$", "<size:large>$1</size:large>")
```

It returns the original value with no changes.  I would expect it to replace the middle `=test=` with `<size:large>test</size:large>`

What am I missing here?

Edit: Okay, I understand why `^` and `$` don't work. The point is that I need something that matches text both at the beginning and end of a line, e.g. a line that contains only "=some text=".  Most of the answers given aren't sufficient, for the following reasons:

`=(.+)=` doesn't have anything to do with line endings, so matches any line with two `=` in it that are not side by side.

`.*=(.+)=.*` matches the whole line, but has the same problem as the previous

`\n=(.+)=\n` gets closer, but won't match two lines in a row (e.g. `test\n=test=\n=test=\ntest`)  It also won't match an instance on the first or last line

`(?<=\n)=(.+)=(?=\n)` almost works, but again won't match an instance on the first or last line

`(?<!.)=(.+)=(?!.)` is the only one that seems will actually match every line that starts and ends with `=`, for example, but $1 contains both the replacement and the original string.

`content = content.replaceAll("(?<=(\n|^))=(.+)=(?=(\n|$))", "<size:large>$2</size:large>");` is the only answer that seems to actually do what it should.

Comment: This appears to be working: `content.replaceAll("(?<!.)=(.+)=(?!.)", "<size:large>$1</size:large>")`

Comment: `(?<!.)` and `(?<=\n)` can you please explain this regex syntax? I am actually confused by `<!` and `<=`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your original regex works fine if you turn on multiline mode, using `(?m)`:

```
content = content.replaceAll("(?m)^=(.+)=$", "<size:large>$1</size:large>");
```

Now `^` and `$` do indeed match at line boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

The best way to deal with this is to set [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE). Using `MULTILINE`, `^` and `$` will match on lines that are separated using only `\n`, and will similarly handle the beginning of input and the end of input.

Using `String.replaceAll` you need to set these *within* the pattern using an embedded flag expression `(?m)`, for `MULTILINE`:

```
content = str.replaceAll("(?m)^=(.+)=$", "<size:large>$1</size:large>");
```

If you *don't* use `MULTILINE`,  you need to use *positive* lookahead and lookbehind for the `\n`, and the regex gets complicated in order to match the first line, and the last line if there's no `\n` at the end, e.g. if our input is: `=test=\n=test=\n=test=\n=test=`.

```
String pattern = "(?<=(^|\n))=(.+)=(?=(\n|$))";
content = str.replaceAll(pattern, "<size:large>$2</size:large>");
```

In this pattern we're supplying options for the lookbehind: `\n` *or* beginning of input, `(^|\n)`; and for the lookahead: `\n` *or* end of input, `(\n|$)`. Notice that we need to use `$2` as the captured group reference in the replacement because of the group introduced by the first *or*.

We can make the pattern more complicated by introducing the alternatives in the lookahead/lookbehind in non-capturing groups, which look like `(?:)`:

```
String pattern = "(?<=(?:^|\n))=(.+)=(?=(?:\n|$))";
content = str.replaceAll(pattern, "<size:large>$1</size:large>");
```

Now we're back to using `$1` as the captured group in the replacement.

Comment: actually, this won't match the first or last line, will it?  Negative lookahead is probably better...

Comment: I don't see any need for the UNIX_LINES modifier.  In fact, if the text does have DOS-style line separators (`\r\n`), the `(?dm)` modifier will make the regex fail, while `(?m)` alone works fine.

Comment: @AlanMoore quite right about UNIX_LINE. I edited the answer to rely on only MULTILINE. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Java String objects `\n` isn't considered a beginning of a line or an end of a line. It's a line feed. To match this, you need to change your code to

```
String content = "test\n=test=\ntest";
content = content.replaceAll("\n=(.+)=\n", "\n<size:large>$1</size:large>\n");
```

What `^` and `$` match, are the beginning and the end of the String object itself.

If you're reading from a file, the newline could be a CRLF character in which case you want to match `\r` too. In that case you need to use a regex like this

```
content = content.replaceAll("[\n\r]=(.+)=[\n\r]", "\n<size:large>$1</size:large>\n");
```

If you need to match to work in multiple instances in multiple 'lines' in the same String, you should first split the String to multiple lines.

```
String content = "test\n=test=\n=test=\ntest";
String[] pieces = content.split("[\r\n]");
StringBuilder replaced = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0; i<pieces.length; i++) {
    String piece = pieces[i].replaceAll("^=(.+)=$", "<size:large>$1</size:large>");
    replaced.append(piece);
    replaced.append('\n');
}
```

Comment: This also replaces the newlines in the result. You'll need to add them back in the replacement string.

Comment: I'm not sure about Android here, but from my tests in plain Java, it seems that the trailing `\n` is not recognized.

Comment: @Thomas Not sure why. It's working for me. Are you reading the string from a file, or from a the same string object as in the example? From a file, the regex would need to match either `\r` or `\n`, to account for the CRLF.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm trying; the problem is that this doesn't work for say `test\n=test=\n=test=\ntest` - it only matches the first, not the second instance.

Comment: That's because once `\n=test=\n` has been matched, the characters following it are `=test=\n`. There's no \n in the next set to match the regex.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just pointing out that this answer doesn't work perfectly for me.  See the comment to my question for an answer that seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you already stated, it is a matter of begin/end markers of the regex. `^` is not the beginning of a line but of the entire string, likewise `$` is the end of the entire string.

Try to change the expression: `^.*=(.+)=.*$` or leave those markers out: `=(.+)=`

To match the beginning of the line, you could use this: `(?:^|\n)=(.*)=`. From my tests in plain Java, it seems as if the trailing line break is not recognized, but that might be different in Android.

Comment: okay, I see that now; is there no way to make it match beginning and end of a line?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I have an answer... this seems to work:

```
content = content.replaceAll("(?<!.)=(.+)=(?!.)", "<size:large>$1</size:large>")
```

Doesn't it?

Edit: The above doesn't work, for some reason it copies the original text and places it after the substituted text... here's what finally did work:

```
content = content.replaceAll("(?<=(\n|^))=(.+)=(?=(\n|$))", "<size:large>$2</size:large>");
```

Comment: It's unclear. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for pattern say that `.` _may or may not match line terminators_.

Comment: I am guessing the `.` only matches line terminators if you set `Pattern.DOTALL`, no?

Comment: yeah that's the reason behind _may or may not_, but I'm still not sure how this applies to `String.replaceAll`; maybe only via `(?s)` in the pattern. The `DOTALL` bit says that `.` shouldn't match newlines by default.

Comment: Based on testing, I can confirm that it doesn't by default.